# How can I revoke all oAuth tokens for a single user

Tags: security, oauth2

My user has the standard system administrator profile, and I have a very long string of 113 oAuth tokens on my user going back to 2012.  I would like to remove all of them and start fresh, as it seems good to not have all these open tokens around for apps I no longer use, given that I'm an admin.  None of these tokens are for an integration, as we use dedicated integration users, so its just a long list of apps over the course of 5+ years.

[image: a small set of the long list]

I cannot find any way to do this in bulk - only option is to click remove on each one individually.  I can see that on a given connected app there is a 'revoke all' button, but no such functionality on a user's list of connected apps.

Is there any way to do this in bulk, without clicking remove next to each one?  Or is there another way to approach this - ie resetting password?  Or is this just not a security issue for other reasons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write some code to query the `OAuthToken` for a given user then make callouts to the [revoke endpoint](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/oauth_revoking_tokens.htm) for each of the records using the `deleteToken`.

> A token that can be used at the revoke OAuth token endpoint to remove this token.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_oauthtoken.htm

Building it out to a VF page or some other tool to do it in one fell swoop. If you just need it this once, clicking revoke on each one may be the quickest way though